# Tooltip content is displayed at the right side of the column when the text is too long

Tags: html, css, angular

When the content is too long, tooltip data is displayed to the right of the column.
Tooltip position is bottom, for smaller contents it is positioned properly.
When the content is longer the tooltip data is displayed farther right.

Cannot share code due to company policy.

Please help

Comment: Without code its difficult to help...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular material tooltip you can follow tooltip position instruction and maybe set position to bottom. It may help you solve your problem
[Angular material tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview)